# How do I set all read only Sharepoint 365 sites to NoAccess with Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, permissions

I am trying to figure out how to create a script to set all the sites with lockstate "ReadOnly" to lockstate "NoAccess" without going through each site individually and changing the lockstate.

I have so far figured out how to get a list of all SharePoint sites in the collection with Get-SPOSite, how to check their lockstate and how to change it but I don't know where to start with writing the script to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following PowerShell script as an administrator:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell -DisableNameChecking
 
#Config Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="https://crescentintranet-admin.sharepoint.com"

#Get Credentials to connect to SharePoint Admin Center
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Center
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL –Credential $Cred
 
#Get All site collections
$SiteCollections = Get-SPOSite -Limit All
Write-Host "Total Number of Site collections Found:"$SiteCollections.count -f Yellow
 
#Array to store Result
$ResultSet = @()
 
#Loop through each site collection and retrieve details
Foreach ($Site in $SiteCollections)
{
    Write-Host "Processing Site Collection :"$Site.URL -f Yellow
    
    if($Site.LockState -eq 'ReadOnly'){

    #Get site collection details   
    $Result = new-object PSObject
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Title" -Value $Site.Title
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Url" -Value $Site.Url
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "LockState" -Value $Site.LockState
    $ResultSet += $Result

} 

}
  
#List Result
$ResultSet 
 
Foreach ($Result in $ResultSet)
{
    set-sposite $Result.Url -LockState NoAccess
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup, that worked a perfectly, thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am glad this can help you. Have a nice day!